# in JSF - How to rerender a component on button press. (The smart way?)

Tags: html, jsf, richfaces

I have a simple HTMLCommandButton that I want to cause a rerender to another component.
I know of a simple way to do that - add an ajax support object and have it run on "onclick" event and rerender.

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{actions.submitToDB}">
  <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="Button0" />
</h:commandButton>
```

I figured there has to be a smarter way to do this with the on* attributes of the HTML CommandButton but I'm not sure what to write to cause the rerender (Using this alleged method)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't a smarter way in the common case. This is the way to do it. You will have to do the following

- set `type="button"` on the button.
- set the action on the `<a4j:support>` rather than on the button istself.

In this particular case (a button) a shortcut will be:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Submit"
       action="#{actions.submitToDB}" reRender="Button0" />
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess I can just as well stick with the support object.

Comment: @Ben see my update. You'd have to do something more in order to use the support tag. I'd recommend the `a4j:commandButton`

Comment: +1; Maybe this is what you meant by your last comment, but I'm not sure.  It seems using `a4j:commandButton` instead of `h:commandButton` is what fixed this for me, as that made the UI stop doing a full POST + refresh cycle.